# How can I extend an LVM volume using lvextend?

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm

Very simple question today: what sort of path is the `lvextend` command looking for?

`lvextend`'s error message asks for "a logical volume path", however this is very misleading in my opinion, since the output of `lvdisplay` presents something called an "LV Path", which is NOT - contrary to reasonable expectation - accepted as a valid input to `lvextend`.

```
root@kub2022:~# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/sam/sandbox
  LV Name                sandbox
  VG Name                sam
  LV UUID                xHIVJX-Ewtq-FTSf-AEjW-8gKa-VaDL-dbzG2f
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time kub2022, 2023-03-14 02:27:53 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                <48.83 GiB
  Current LE             12500
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     131064
  Block device           253:3

root@kub2022:~# lvextend -r +10000 /dev/sam/sandbox
  Please specify a logical volume path.
  Run `lvextend --help' for more information.
```

I tried a few more variations such as `lvextend -r +10000 sam sandbox`, `lvextend -r +10000 sam/sandbox`, etc, all of which resulted in the same error message.

Here's part of the output of `vgdisplay`, in case that's relevant:

```
root@kub2022:~# vgdisplay 

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               sam
  #
  # etc...
  #
  VG Size               <432.02 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              110597
  Alloc PE / Size       50000 / 195.31 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       60597 / <236.71 GiB
  # etc...
```

How can I properly format `lvextend` to extend `sandbox` by 10GB?

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The command you search for is:

```
lvextend -r -L+10G /dev/sam/sandbox
```

You should add `-l` or `-L` before defining the size.

Comment: `-f` stands for `--force` though (and `-r` is already there)

Comment: @TomYan, my mistake, will correct it. :)

Comment: I dont think the -f or r  is needed.  I routinely do this withouth those flags.

Comment: @davidgo,  Actually I recently get know about this flag, before I did the filesystem extend by hand too :)

Comment: Yeah, not sure -f " Override various checks, confirmations and protections.  Use with extreme caution." is ideal in most cases.  -r which tries to resize the filesystem is interesting (and I did not know about it - my usage case is a little different. )